# Automating actions in OneNote using AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I want to assign keyboard shortcut to various actions in Microsoft OneNote. (Its annoying that OneNote has different keyboard shortcuts than Word and Excel). Also OneNote does not support macros. So I am trying out AutoHotKey.

I want to make selected text red, when I hit `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+r`. I wrote simple script file:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

#IfWinActive - OneNote$ ; ------ only in windows with title ending with "- OneNote"

^!+r::
Send, !hfcm^{PgDn}!r255{Tab}5{Tab}0{Enter} ; red (255, 0, 0)
return

#IfWinActive ; ------ end of section restricted to specific windows
```

But it does not do anything when I hit those keys. When I remove `#IfWinActive` lines, it starts working. How can I make it work only within one note?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be trying to use the regex [title match mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm). To use it, you'd need to specify it first on top of your script like this:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx

#IfWinActive, - OneNote$
^!+r::Send, !hfcm^{PgDn}!r255{Tab}5{Tab}0{Enter} ; red (255, 0, 0)
#IfWinActive
```

Also compacted your hotkey into a one liner, since that's what it is.
And that should work (assuming it's matching the correct title, I can't test it, I don't use OneNote)

---

Personally I'd recommend matching with [`ahk_exe`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#ahk_exe) though. This will (likely) make no difference in practice, but it's very convenient in my opinion.

So assuming the executable running OneNote would be named `OneNote.exe` (check its actual name from e.g. task manager, or with e.g. WindowSpy*) you'd do this (don't use Regex title match mode with this):

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe OneNote.exe
^!+r::Send, !hfcm^{PgDn}!r255{Tab}5{Tab}0{Enter} ; red (255, 0, 0)
#IfWinActive
```

---

<sup>* WindowSpy a neat little script that'll be found in your AHK install folder</sup>

Comment: I tried that as shown [here](https://codeshare.io/2p9PrV). I can recolor text to any color after coloring it to red and purple. But once I color it green, it does not change its color again to red or purple. That is selecting text, hitting `^!+g` turns it green, but then hitting `^!+r` just plays a error tone from laptop speaker and does not change color to red. Also want to know what is after `;` ? Are they comments? Also can I delete first four lines? They are auto generated.

Comment: Yes, first four lines can be deleted, `;` indicates the beginning of a comment, and I can't test your key combinations for you because I don't have/use OneNote.